# How to create a C++ virtual function in abstract class allowing to return any kind of type

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, abstract

I've coded an abstract class `A`.

Is there a possibility to create a virtual function `value()`, which will return "whatever" and when we create a derived class `B` implement here function `value()` and return from it anything?

Here is an example and an explaination of my intent:

```
class A {
    public virtual void value() = 0;
};

template < class T >
class B : public A {
    private T content;
    public T value() { return content; };
};
```

As you can see I'm trying to create an universal container, which could be used especially in that case:

```
std::vector< A > container;
B< int > bint;
B< std::string > bstring;
B< zoo::monkey > bmonkey;
container.push_back( bint);
container.push_back( bstring );
container.push_back( bmonkey );
```

Is there a solution to this or is there other, better solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can only have co-variant return types for virtual functions in C++ nothing more.

Comment: To add to Alok's comment, if the base class member returns a type, the derived class members must return something of that type but it can be more specific(derived from the original returned type). Have you though of making all the objects you could want to return inherit from a common parent type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return types of overrides must be [co-variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) to that of the base class function.

A co-variant type can be "replaced" by the compiler with that of another type.  What this means for you is that the base class needs to return something, and the override must return something convertible to that.

In your case, you're returning `void` from the base, and nothing but `void` is co-variant with `void` -- therefore, as written, only a `void` can be returned from the derived class method.

Since you are trying to write a generic class that can be used to store "anything" in a container, I'd suggest you look in to [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) or [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any.html).  Writing a variant-type class from scratch is surprisingly difficult, and is a wheel that's already been invented.

Answer (score 1):

you can still look at boost::any or boost::variant